# SPL objectstorage vs SPL array vs ordinary array

Tags: php, arrays, spl

what is the **difference**,**usage** scenerio between normal ARray, SPL array and SPL datastorage? It would be great if anyone can give some practical example of usage of SPLarray and SPL objectsrorage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of [`SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) is that for a certain subset of use cases for arrays, it is much faster (that subset being arrays that have only integer keys, and a fixed length).  So, for example:

```
$a = array("foo", $bar, 7, ... thousands of values ..., $quux);
$b = \SplFixedArray::fromArray($a);

// here, $b will be much faster to use than $a
```

The usage for this class could literally be anything you could use an array for, but found them to previously be too slow.  A lot of times this is the case in complex calculations on large data sets.  For your typical PHP-based web application or website, there aren't going to be many (if any) cases where you'd *need* the performance boost.

---

The [`SplObjectStorage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) class, however, can be useful in all kinds of typical cases.  It provides a way to map objects to other data.  So, for example, maybe you have a `Route` class that you'd like to provide a mapping to a `Controller` class:

```
$routeOne = new Route(/* ... */);
$routeTwo = new Route(/* ... */);

$controllerOne = new Controller(/* ... */);
$controllerTwo = new Controller(/* ... */);

$controllers = new \SplObjectStorage();

$controllers[$routeOne] = $controllerOne;
$controllers[$routeTwo] = $controllerTwo;

// now you can look up a controller for a given route by:  $controllers[$route]
```

Comment: does it mean in splobjectstorage object can be used as index?

and is it possible to use character index (like associative array) with splArray?

Comment: Yes, you can use objects as indexes in `SplObjectStorage`.  No, you can't use string indexes with `SplFixedArray`.